# Saving Radio List/Checked Value (in table) to plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, plist

I'm doing Objective-C (iOS) development.

Is it possible to save a checked value from a selected row of a table into plist?

Answer (score 1):

If you are populating tableview from plist add some nsnumber field to row data and use `numberWithBool:` and `boolValue` methods to create boolean objects that can be stored into plist...
Or you can always get indexPath.row from selected row in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and add it to array of selected rows or remove it from it, and then serialize that array into plist.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to save in your plist file a boolean but you can use instead @"YES" and @"NO" strings and paste the code if you get stuck.